# Deselecting a date in an ASP.Net Calendar catching a second click

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I am working in n ASP.Net app. where selecting a date on a Calendar means that a task has been completed so that record goes to a SQL Database. However, sometimes users select a date by mistake so I need to give them the opportunity to deselect the date somehow.
I thought that the most natural way to let users to do this, is to click again in the selected date. 
I tried to implement this through the "SelectionChanged" Calendar's event but it did not triggered clicking again on the selected date, which makes sense because actually the selected date did not change.
Then I tried using the "DayRender" event. So, I compare SelectedDate with VisibleDate, clearing the dates if both properties have the same date and selects the date otherwise.
It works the first time that the event is called, but then the event is triggered again when the next day has to be rendered and clears the date :D

```
protected void Claim_Edit_PickupDone_Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  Calendar cal = (Calendar)sender;
  if (cal.SelectedDate == cal.VisibleDate)
  {
     cal.SelectedDates.Clear();
     cal.VisibleDate = DateTime.MinValue;
  }
  else
  {
     cal.VisibleDate = cal.SelectedDate;
     cal.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Goldenrod;
  }      
}
```

I also placed a checkbox inside the template, but it seems unnatural to me.
Could somebody please help me to catch the second click? Or maybe it would be better to leave the checkbox?
Best regards.

Comment: why can't you simply write textbox_textchanged event? let users empty the textbox of the selected date and send instruction to db to clear that field

Comment: @techspider. Hey, thanks for sharing your ideas. That does not sound to bad at all. Let me see how it goes and I will go back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to write good logic rather than doing arbitrary code.

I would prefer writing TextBox_TextChanged event to check if the TextBox is empty, and fire a DB call to clear the Date field.

On the contrary you can use the solution implemented here in this [topic](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Clear-Selected-Date-of-ASPNet-AJAX-CalendarExtender-using-JavaScript.aspx).

Comment: On the topic that you are providing, the button triggers the logic, what is pretty much what I did with the checkbox. And I am still chewing the idea of leaving a textbox because it leads to a nightmare controlling what the users enter. I have to think about it during the weekend but thank you so much for sharing ideas. :)

Comment: I am keeping your solution where a button clears the selected date. It is clearer than the checkbox because it only needs one line of code, which makes it much more easy to maintain. I wrote the code again in a couple of minutes. Thank you very much.

Comment: exactly; that is what i meant :) no problem